# Pandas slicing rows with another stride

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here is the data I have:

```
                     o  h  l  c
time                           
2019.02.04 01:21:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:22:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:23:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:24:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:25:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:26:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:27:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:28:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:29:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:30:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:31:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:32:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:33:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:34:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:35:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:36:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:37:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:38:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:39:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:40:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:41:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:42:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:43:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:44:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:45:00  x  x  x  x
```

With time as `index`, I have tried separating the values. But was not successful.

Starting from the beginning, I want to slice every 3 rows while skipping 2 rows between each slice.

I tried this:

```
df_candle = df[5:400+2]
```

But this is simple series from `5 to 402`. I thought it will help me jump with 2.

I am expecting the result as:

```
time,o,h,l,c
2019.02.04 01:21:00,x,x,x,x
2019.02.04 01:22:00,x,x,x,x
2019.02.04 01:23:00,x,x,x,x
2019.02.04 01:26:00,x,x,x,x
2019.02.04 01:27:00,x,x,x,x
2019.02.04 01:28:00,x,x,x,x
2019.02.04 01:31:00,x,x,x,x
2019.02.04 01:32:00,x,x,x,x
2019.02.04 01:33:00,x,x,x,x
2019.02.04 01:36:00,x,x,x,x
2019.02.04 01:37:00,x,x,x,x
2019.02.04 01:38:00,x,x,x,x
2019.02.04 01:41:00,x,x,x,x
2019.02.04 01:42:00,x,x,x,x
2019.02.04 01:43:00,x,x,x,x
```

Please let me know what I can do.

Comment: Jump don't work the way you are expecting

Comment: @coldspeed Had you tested the sample I have given and is it giving the same result?

Comment: No, but then again it isn't clear what you want because that expected output differs from the description in your question.

Comment: @coldspeed I have shown what I expect Sir. I tried someting that would have helped me but it is not. I wanted to get the output as shown in the expected one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you're looking for variable step slicing. One option I can think of is using `groupby` and `cumcount` to build a filter mask:

```
df[df.groupby(pd.RangeIndex(len(df)) // 5).cumcount() < 3]

                     o  h  l  c
time                           
2019.02.04 01:21:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:22:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:23:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:26:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:27:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:28:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:31:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:32:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:33:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:36:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:37:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:38:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:41:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:42:00  x  x  x  x
2019.02.04 01:43:00  x  x  x  x
```

Comment: Can I start it from a possible point? For example If I want to take the dataframe from the 5 to 400 only and rest should not be used, can I do that?

Comment: @JafferWilson As a first step; do `df1 = df.iloc[5:400]`, then you can run this code on `df1`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df1=df[5:400]
print(df1.drop([i for i in df1.index.tolist() if (str(i)[-1] in ['8','9']) or (str(i+5)[-1] in ['8','9'])]))
```

Output:

```
                   time        o        h        l        c
5   2019.02.04 01:26:00  1.14558  1.14558  1.14556  1.14556
6   2019.02.04 01:27:00  1.14556  1.14556  1.14556  1.14556
7   2019.02.04 01:28:00  1.14556  1.14556  1.14549  1.14551
10  2019.02.04 01:31:00  1.14554  1.14554  1.14546  1.14546
11  2019.02.04 01:32:00  1.14551  1.14551  1.14541  1.14544
12  2019.02.04 01:33:00  1.14543  1.14543  1.14541  1.14541
15  2019.02.04 01:36:00  1.14557  1.14558  1.14553  1.14556
16  2019.02.04 01:37:00  1.14556  1.14556  1.14556  1.14556
17  2019.02.04 01:38:00  1.14557  1.14557  1.14556  1.14556
20  2019.02.04 01:41:00  1.14555  1.14555  1.14555  1.14555
21  2019.02.04 01:42:00  1.14555  1.14555  1.14551  1.14551
22  2019.02.04 01:43:00  1.14555  1.14555  1.14551  1.14551
```

Comment: Sir had you seen my data? The solution you are giving is not working and giving the same result to me. I have pasted the expected result also.

Comment: @JafferWilson How come, it gives desired result for me tho, had you tried `print(df[5:400][::2])`?

Comment: I am getting the output as: https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/8df2981f8fdb7d8e8e38dbf9cd85fc8f You see is not the expected result Sir.

Comment: @JafferWilson Sorry,  can you explain the logic please?

Comment: Sure, I am taking the values from the from some row till some row. In between that I am keeping the first three rows and removing the next two rows then again the three rows are kept and two rows are remove. and so on.... Am I clear, Sir?

Comment: I didn't got you sir? What you mean to say?

Comment: @JafferWilson Got up, gonna be a minute.